# The transition of my Vue modal component in my Twig file is not working

Tags: vuejs2, css-transitions

In my component Modal.vue I have my template:

```
<template>
    <transition name="overlay-fade">
      <div class="fixed inset-0 w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-green-400 z-40 opacity-50">
        <div class="p-8 bg-white w-full max-w-2xl flex-col flex">
          <slot>Modal content</slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
</template>
```

And the styles:

```
<style>
  .overlay-fade-enter-active,
  .overlay-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.8s;
  }
  .overlay-fade-enter,
  .overlay-fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

In header twig template `header.html.twig`, where Vue is bind through `<div id="menu">`, I placed my components:

```
<div id="menu">

 <hamburger-button @click="isOpen = !isOpen"></hamburger-button>

  <menu-modal :class="isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'">
    {{ page.navigation }}
  </menu-modal>

</div>
```

My overlay is not fading in. The transition is not working, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `appear` to your transition element to trigger it on the initial render.

```
<transition appear name="overlay-fade">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/magcnkro/

Comment: I've added a working example. It's probably because the modal is being rendered before it's visible. Can you upload the parent component code?

Comment: Try adding `v-if="isOpen"` to your menu-modal tag

Comment: last question just to understand. If I add `v-if="isOpen"` within my component `Modal.vue` into the `<template>` section then it's not working. If I add it to `<menu-modal v-if="isOpen">`(in the template where I register the Modal.vue component), then it's working. Why is this? Just to understand how it's working.

Comment: Because components cannot see the properties of their parents unless you pass them as props. So you could do `<menu-modal isOpen="isOpen">` then register isOpen as a prop in your component `props : ['isOpen']`, then you can use it in your component template (but not on the template tag itself).